# Running code from another class

Tags: android

hi I'm new to android programming and I'm creating an app that part of it generate Qrcode by using The Zxing library 
I created a class with a method Encode contains block of code that generate the qrcode

```
public void Encode(String Text_To_Encode )
{
     final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.QrImageView);
    String qrData = "Ahmed";
    int qrCodeDimention = 500;

    QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder(qrData, null,
            Contents.Type.TEXT, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(), qrCodeDimention);

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();

     imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Whenever I call this method in Oncreate() method in MainActivity the app Unfortunately has stopped
but when I take this block of code and run it directly in the MainActivity it runs perfectly 
I need to know what I do wrong ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From normal class use Activity context to access views :

```
public void Encode(String Text_To_Encode,Activity activity )
{
     final ImageView imageView = 
                           (ImageView)activity.findViewById(R.id.QrImageView);
    .....
}
```

From Activity call `Encode` method by passing Activity context:

```
Encode(Text_To_Encode,ActivityName.this)
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying . . . . and pass Mainactivity.this when I call it ??

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line of code: `final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.QrImageView);`

You see, you're trying to modify ONE SPECIFIC ImageView. That ImageView belongs to an Activity or Fragment, not to the Application. When you call that method in any Activity or Fragment that `R.id.QrImageView` does not exist, it will crash because it can't find the ImageView (which is because that ImageView is out-of-scope).

To solve this problem, I would improve your code by RETURNING THE BITMAP in the method.

To be clear, your method should look like this:

```
public Bitmap Encode(String Text_To_Encode )
{
String qrData = "Ahmed";
int qrCodeDimention = 500;
QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder(qrData, null,
        Contents.Type.TEXT, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(), qrCodeDimention);
try {
    return qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();
} catch (WriterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Now, in  your Activity or Fragment, simply use `imageView.setImageBitmap(qrClass.encode(String textToEncode));`